# Connect, Post and Get data from REST API for my android application

Tags: java, android, rest, django-rest-framework

I have been searching for a proper tutorial or guidance for this. I am in the middle of building a project (A delivery platform), the only thing remaining is connecting to a network, reading the data and posting data into the REST API. Can anyone please help me regarding this? I followed Googles Developer Documentation and it came of no good. A nudge in the proper direction would do. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use retrofit, you can check and find tutorial on youtube

Answer (score 0):

You can use retrofit2 framework to build app that will get, post, put, delete data to your REST API. It's easy, you can follow on this tutorial:

https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-beyond-android-retrofit-for-java-projects

Comment: I am currently following Android Devs documentation. Connect to a Network. Is that a good one?

Comment: Yes, that's good. But it's a little bit hard. You should better firstly follow examples before diving into android documents.

Comment: Retrofit does not help me in this case. How about Android Asynchronous Http Client? Will that work? That seems easier.